# ReactJS Hooks: Form submitting blank values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, chakra-ui

I have a form with `hidden` `input` called `campaingid` receiving data from URL parameters through an external script.

See the input code:

```
<Input name="campaignid" type="hidden" onChange={e => setCampaignid(e.target.value)} />
```

It's working fine... the `value` field is being filled correctly with the URL parameters.

My problem surges at the following step... When I submit the form, the `campaingid` value disappears.

See my variable state:

```
const [campaignid, setCampaignid] = useState('')
```

When I submit the form, it retrieves blank data at `campaigning`

I think there is a mistake in the usage of `onChange` events. Idk...

Someone can help me?

Full code: https://github.com/stridesdigital/ac-chakraUI-angelina-cortinas/blob/main/src/components/Forms/heroform.tsx

Comment: I don't see anything regarding the value from the URL parameters (in the URL)?

Comment: Can you provide the full code + submit?

Comment: Would you be able to share more code? How does the value on the input get set? How does submission happen? Try producing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.

Comment: Hey folk, the full code: https://github.com/stridesdigital/ac-chakraUI-angelina-cortinas/blob/main/src/components/Forms/heroform.tsx

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question. Adding an external repo is fine, but the question should be self contained and not depend on external resources.

Answer (score 0):

move your `submit` function below `useState`'s

First rule of hooks:

**Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

also if it doesn't work then wrap `submit` in `useCallback`
refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback